# Unit testing iphone app withXcode, SenTestCase and C++ dependencies

Tags: iphone, xcode, unit-testing

I have a iphone project with a embedded (for ease of use) open source C++ project in it (meaning its folders are just a group inside the project). Following Apple's tutorial on [unit testing Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/1-Articles/CreatingTests.html), I could run the tests no problem, provided the only imported files are from Objective-C classes.

However, whenever I run tests that import C/C++ code, the test target fails on tons of "file not found". Any idea on how to solve this, without turning all C/C++ deps on system files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually just configuring the search path on the test target solved this. Which is kinda odd, as the project target is a dependency. However, it lead to other issues, which this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013118/iphone-unit-testing-symbols-not-found-when-calling-custom-code) took care of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the .mm extension for your C files, if you're not using it already...

If we're talking about **TONS** of files, go ahead and try renaming one and see if that removes it from the "file-not-found-pile".